# LFSR expected period

Tags: lfsr

What is the expected value of the length of the period of a n-bit linear-feedback shift register with a random tap?
I am asking because I am curious what security issues would appear if the tap would be generated randomly.

Comment: The period's length depends on both the initial state and the tap(s). It goes from $1$ (for the all-zero state) to $2^n-1$ (for another initial state, and $x^n+x^k+1$ primitive; a list of $k$ for $n\le400$ is [here](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-trinomial-primpoly-short.txt)). I can't tell the _expected value_ as asked, hence this is not an answer.

Comment: If the tap positions are random, the math behind calculating their period will be quite complex.